# ¿Qué envía una imagen dentro de un form de HTML con el método post?

Tags: php, html

Si creo un `<form>` con method `POST` (cuyo atributo `action` llama a un programa PHP) y un `<input type="image">` dentro, si hago click en la imagen ¿llega algún valor en alguna variable de `$_POST`? y, en caso afirmativo, ¿qué valor tendrá?.

Comment: Ya probaste enviar un valor e imprimir dicha variable con var_dump?

Comment: Esta ayuda me ha valido para seguir adelante.

Answer (score 3):

los valores que llegan en un `<input type="file">` no llegan en la variables `$_POST` si no en variables tipo `$_FILES` y debes agregar `enctype="multipart/form-data"` en el `<form>` la etiqueta form quedaria algo asi `<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">` y el archivo que recibe el formulario imprimes osea .. `var_dump($_FILES);`

Comment: Quizás me expresé mal pero no me refería a usar un input type="file" sino un input type="image" y lo que quería era controlar cuando el usuario hace clic en ello. Me sirvió la idea de hacer un var_dump() para ver que me llegaban por post las coordenadas donde había hecho clic sobre la imagen. Ya con eso puedo controlar que ha sido pulsada la imagen

Answer (score 1):

en html

```
<form action="altaArticulos.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"class="carga-form "><br>
<fieldset>
            Nombre: <br>
            <input type="text" name="nombre" class="carga">
     </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
            <input type="file" name="isologo" class="imaAni mt-4" accept="img-a/*" id="image">
     </fieldset>
```

> en php

```
if(!isset($_POST['nombre'])){
    header("Location:ingresarArticulos.php");

}else{
        $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["isologo"]["name"]);
        $extension = end($temp);
        $isologo="";
        $random=rand(1,999999);

            //Verificamos que sea una imagen
        if ($_FILES["isologo"]["error"] > 0){
            //verificamos que venga algo en el input file
            echo "Error numero: " . $_FILES["isologo"]["error"] . "<br>";
        }else{
            //subimos la imagen

            $isologo= $random.'_'.$_FILES["isologo"]["name"];
            if(file_exists("ProductosImg/".$random.'_'.$_FILES["isologo"]["name"])){
                echo $_FILES["isologo"]["name"] . " Ya existe. ";
            }else{
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["isologo"]["tmp_name"],
                "ProductosImg/" .$random.'_'.$_FILES["isologo"]["name"]);
                echo "Archivo guardado en " . "ProductosImg/" .$random.'_'. $_FILES["isologo"]["name"];


                        }

        }
```

}

> debes asegurarte de tener la carpeta donde irán las imágenes en mi caso "ProductosImg/" espero te ayude Saludos

Answer (score 1):

**¿Llega algún valor en alguna variable de $_POST?**

No, llegan a la variable global `$_FILES`.

**Y, en caso afirmativo, ¿qué valor tendrá?**

El contenido de la variable `$_FILES` está detallado en la documentación de PHP.

Te recomiendo que, ante cualquier duda, consultes el manual de PHP la información sobre [subida de archivos](https://php.net/es/file-upload.post-method) y la variable global [`$_FILES`](https://php.net/es/reserved.variables.files).

El manual te propone dos ejemplos, uno enviando un único archivo y otro con soporte para el envío de múltiples archivos. También te informa de qué parámetros limitan el tamaño máximo del archivo que se puede enviar o que puede recibir un script de PHP.

En cualquier caso, insisto, es la variable global `$_FILES` la que recibe los datos relacionados con los archivos recibidos y no la variable `$_POST`.

---

De la documentación:

> El array global [`$_FILES`](https://php.net/es/reserved.variables.files) contendrá toda la información de los los ficheros subidos. Su contenido en el formulario del ejemplo es el siguiente. Observe que se asume el empleo del nombre *fichero_usuario* para el fichero subido, tal como se utiliza en el script de ejemplo anterior. Este puede ser cualquier nombre.
>
> - `$_FILES['fichero_usuario']['name']`: El nombre original del fichero en la máquina del cliente.
> - `$_FILES['fichero_usuario']['type']`: El tipo MIME del fichero, si el navegador proporcionó esta información. Un ejemplo sería "image/gif". Este tipo MIME, sin embargo, no se comprueba en el lado de PHP y por lo tanto no se garantiza su valor.
> - `$_FILES['fichero_usuario']['size']`: El tamaño, en bytes, del fichero subido.
> - `$_FILES['fichero_usuario']['tmp_name']`: El nombre temporal del fichero en el cual se almacena el fichero subido en el servidor.
> - `$_FILES['fichero_usuario']['error']`: El código de error asociado a esta subida.
>
> Por defecto, los ficheros se almacenan en el directorio temporal predeterminado del servidor, a menos que se haya indicado otra ubicación con la directiva [`upload_tmp_dir`](https://php.net/es/ini.core#ini.upload-tmp-dir) en `php.ini`. Se puede cambiar el directorio predeterminado del servidor estableciendo la variable de entorno `TMPDIR` en el entorno en que se ejecuta PHP. Configurarlo usando `putenv()` desde un script de PHP no funcionará. Esta variable de entorno también se puede utilizar para asegurarse de que las demás operaciones están trabajando sobre los ficheros subidos.

También quiero hacer hincapié en la siguiente nota:

> **Nota:** Asegúrese de que el formulario de subida de ficheros tiene el atributo `enctype="multipart/form-data"` o de lo contrario la subida de ficheros no funcionará.